# ¿Como centrar mi logo y texto en mi pagina web?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

¿Como puedo hacer que mi pagina este centrada?

Ya lo intente con `center-block` pero no se centra cuando lo muestro en el navegador

File index.html

```css
/* FILE: main.css */

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.quitar-float {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.csss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title> Fenrris Clothing </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-5 center-block quitar-float text-center">
    <img src="./imagenes/l.png">
    <h1>Fenrris Clothing </h1>
    <p>Conoce el nuevo estilo </p>
    <nav>
      <a href=""> Inicio </a>
      <a href=""> Playeras </a>
      <a href=""> Contacto </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El error esta en como estas incluyendo `Bootstrap`, el código correcto es `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

Comment: Efectivamente, es un error de tipografía. Debería cerrarse la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal estimado. He revisado el código que has publicado y tengo los siguientes comentarios:

1. Al utilizar bootstrap, siempre debes colocar un elemento superior de clase **container**. `<div class="container"> AQUI VA TODO TU HTML RESPONSIVE </div>`
2. Según la lógica de bootstrap, los elementos de tipo columna **col-XX-N** (en tu caso col-md-5), deben estar dentro de un elemento de clase **row** `<div class="row"></div>`
3. Tienes un problema con el archivo bootstrap.min.css ya que agregas una **S** de mas en el nombre del archivo **bootstra.min.csss**.
4. He modificado la forma recomendada por bootstrap de incluir bootstrap en tu página.

```css
/* FILE: main.css */

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.quitar-float {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title> Fenrris Clothing </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-5 center-block quitar-float text-center">
    <img src="./imagenes/l.png">
    <h1>Fenrris Clothing </h1>
    <p>Conoce el nuevo estilo </p>
    <nav>
      <a href=""> Inicio </a>
      <a href=""> Playeras </a>
      <a href=""> Contacto </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza magin: 0 auto;

Para centrar lo que seria el bloque.
Y agrega:

text-align:center;

```css
/* FILE: main.css */

.centrado {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Fenrris Clothing </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="centrado">
    <img src="./imagenes/l.png">
    <h1>Fenrris Clothing </h1>
    <p>Conoce el nuevo estilo </p>
    <nav>
      <a href=""> Inicio </a>
      <a href=""> Playeras </a>
      <a href=""> Contacto </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas usando bootstrap, te recomiendo la opinion de marcos usando la clase "container"mpero si sigue dandote problemas intenta solo poner la
 etiqueta `<center>` encierra con esta etiqueta el elemento que quieras centrar `</center>`, podría ser `<center>   <div></div>   </center>` con esto podrás centrar la mayoría de todos los elementos HTML.

Comment: La etiqueta <center> está obsoleta (en ciertos clientes de correos, no tanto, pero..) por lo que considero es un mal consejo hoy día recomendar su uso, porque al ser obsoleta en el momento en que los nuevos navegadores decidan dejar de darle soporte, fallará irremediablemente.